# Difference between を話す and で話す

Tags: particles, particle-を

> 日本語**を**話す
>   日本語**で**話す

I found that those two sentences can be translated as "I speak Japanese".
Is there a difference regarding the particles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, `を` in this case indicates the direct object. You are talking Japanese.

On the other hand `で` indicates the means by which you accomplish the action. You are talking in Japanese, or talking using Japanese.

Note that both sentences could be extended :

- `電話で日本語を話す` : I talk Japanese on the phone (using the phone).
- `日本語で起{お}こった事｛こと｝を話す` :　I talk in Japanese (about) what happened.
- `事実{じじつ}を話す` : To speak the truth

Note that the second example is not the most natural, you would often use について or に関{かん}して to indicate the topic.